# Native call failing in an Angular application with Custom Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am calling some Javascript functions from an Angular component. The Javascript function is more a test function
that resides in a file called testscript.js:

```
function runFunction(aParam) {
   var res = false;

   alert('Hello, Custom Javascript!');
   return (res);
}
```

Note that the parameter aParam is a Javascript object that will eventually be converted into JSON using a 
JQuery function.

I have placed the file in the src/assets folder, and added the following lines to the script section of the
angular.json file:

```
 "scripts": [
    "src/assets/jquery-3.3.1.js",
    "src/assets/testscript.js"
 ],
```

I have a component called jsComponent that I use to call the function:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const runFunction: any;

@Component({
   selector: 'app-js',
   templateUrl: './js.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./js.component.css']
})
export class JsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  callJS(anObj: InfoObj): boolean {
     const res = runFunction(anObj);
     return (res);
  }
}
```

InfoObj is an object that will be converted to JSON and eventually processed:

```
export class InfoObj {
   constructor(
      public aSize: number,
      public someString: string,
      public aMesg: string
    }
}
```

When running the application, the Javascript function runFunction() gets called when callJS() gets called.
The alert properly displays the box with "Hello, Custom Javascript!" without problems.

Unfortunately, things cease to work properly when I make JSON function calls. When I change my runFunction()
code to call a native JSON conversion function:

```
function runFunction(aParam) {
   var res = false;
   var json = JSON.stringify(aParam);

   alert('Hello, Custom Javascript! '+json);
   return (res);
}
```

the runFunction() function fails. It doesn't even display the alert box.

I am obviously missing something. It looks like for some reason the JSON function is being lost of failing to successfully
operate. It is almost as if the JSON function, is not being found and quietly "hanging" the runFunction() call.

Does anyone know why this function fails when a function like this gets called? Is there something I have to do to 
include this call in my testscript.js file? Or is there a declaration I need to make in my component. What am I missing here?

Comment: Nothing in the dev tools console (like error messages)? Also there is no jQuery in your code, `JSON` is a native api object

Comment: Interesting. I did not realize that the JSON was native. I will have to revise my question.  As for the errors: no, nothing shows up on the console. No exceptions, no error messages. The JSON function just appears to be not called and runFunction() hangs.